# SQL Select problem

Tags: sql

I have a problem trying to figure out how to create a query...
Let's assume we have 2 tables like these:

```
TABLE A
id - box1_id - box1count - box2_id - box2_count
1  - 1       - 100       - 2       - 111
2  - 2       - 222       - NULL    - NULL
3  - 2       - 333       - 3       - 1000

TABLE B
id_box - box_Name
1      - HELLO
2      - TEST
3      - HELP
```

I want to write a query that retrive something like that:

```
id_box - box_Name - box_sumcount
1      - HELLO    - 100
2      - TEST     - 666
3      - HELP     - 1000
```

box_sumcount is the sum of box1_count or box2_count based on box1_id or box2_id are equal to id_box...

Comment: first, shoot the person who designed that table structure...

Comment: breaks integrity rules... The box sum should be a view that actually does a Sum() query. Idealy you might have  a "pallet" class and a "PalletBox" class. Each pallet has many boxes. Each box has 1 count. This way if you have 3 or 1000 boxes you don't need to redo your table structure.

Comment: It is a very bad table structure. In particular the fact that you have two of the "same" thing stored in each separate record, instead of two  separate records.  In general, the existence of columns with numbers in their names (box1, box2) is an indication of a problem in the database.

Comment: That table structure is awful. Needs to be normalized BADLY. With a structure like that, the difficulty of all queries is going to be needlessly more complicated than they need to be. (like this one). If it is at all possible, I suggest you rework that table to at least 2nd normal form, even if it is extra work now. You will thank me later.

Comment: Why is id_box 2's total = 666?  Shouldn't it be either 333 or 555?

Comment: @Larry Lustig 111+222+333 (add up all the box 2s) It confused me at first too due to the badly structured table.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Shooting is too good.

Comment: ok thank you all, I changed the table structure now it's more more easy and understandable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TableB.id_Box,TableB.Boxname, Sum(BC.BoxCount)
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT box1_id as boxid, box1Count as boxCount
   UNION 
   SELECT box2_id as boxid, box2Count as boxCount
  ) BC
 ON (TableB.id_box=BC.Boxid)
 GROUP BY TableB.id_Box, TableB.Boxname
```

Comment: I changed the table structure, but still a useful query :)